# Folium: How to highlight a pair of markers when one of the pair is clicked

Tags: folium

**Background:**

I currently have a CSV list of 1000+ lines of arrival `loc_list[0],loc_list[1]` and departure `[loc_list[2],loc_list[3]` (a pair of) geolocations.

**Question:**

Is there a way of highlighting the the pair of locations when one of the two is clicked?

**Snippet of code:**

```
    folium.Marker([loc_list[0],loc_list[1]], icon=folium.Icon(color='green'), popup='<strong>Trip {}</strong>'.format(LOCATION_COUNT)).add_to(m)
    folium.Marker([loc_list[2],loc_list[3]], icon=folium.Icon(color='red'), popup='<strong>Trip {}</strong>'.format(LOCATION_COUNT)).add_to(m)
```